# How to disable autorotation on AVPlayer Video?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have a `ViewController` with an `AVPlayer`, but the video is autorotate even when I have set portrait as the only supported orientation in `info.plist` and in delegate `supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor` function.

I have search for documentation without succeed.

Here is some code:

```
var videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
var player = AVPlayer.init(url: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: urlString))
videoPlayer?.player = player
videoPlayer?.view.frame = self.view.frame
videoPlayer?.showsPlaybackControls = false

self.present(videoPlayer!, animated: false, completion: {action in
 self.player?.play()
})
```

Comment: Can you, please, share some code?

Comment: Sorry for late, here is some code.

Comment: Can you subclass `AVPlayerViewController` and return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape` from `supportedInterfaceOrientations`?

Comment: Thanks!. This works, please post it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by subclassing `AVPlayerViewController` and return `UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait` from `supportedInterfaceOrientations` here is the code.

```
class PlayerVideoViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
    return .portrait
}}
```

Thank you to Rhythmic Fistman for the answer.